# Questions about replacing a string of banned words with substitutes with a given sentence using for loop

Tags: python, string

This is the question:

Implement a function called `mask_out` in `q3.py`.

- The mask_out function takes in three parameter:

  - sentence (type: str)
  - banned (type: str)
  - substitutes (type: str)
- This function returns a string that is a copy of sentence, except that if a character in sentence is found in banned, this character will be replaced with a corresponding character in substitutes whose index in substitutes is the same as the index of the banned character in the parameter banned.

For example, if banned is `'abc'` and substitutes is `'xyz'`, then every `'a'` in sentence is replaced with `'x'`, every `'b'` is replaced with `'y'`, and every `'c'` is replaced with `'z'`.

You can assume the following:

- Banned contains unique characters, i.e., there are no duplicated characters in banned.
- Substitutes contains at least one character.
- Banned is either of the same length as substitutes or longer than substitutes. When banned is longer than substitutes, the additional characters in banned will be replaced with the first character in substitutes. For example, if banned is `'abcde'` and substitutes is `'xy'`, then `'c'`,
  `'d'` and `'e'` will be replaced by `'x'`.

**My Code:**

```py
def mask_out(sentence, banned, substitutes):
    store=""

    if len(banned)==len(substitutes):
        for ch in sentence:
            if ch in banned:
                for i in range(0,len(banned)):
                    if banned[i]==ch:
                        store=store+substitutes[i]
            if ch not in banned:
                store=store+ch
    return store
    if len(banned) > len(substitutes):
         for ch in sentence:
            if ch in banned:
                for i in range(0,len(banned)):
                    if i<=len(substitute):

                        if banned[i]==ch:
                            store=store+substitutes[i]
                    if i>len(substitute):
                        store=store+substitutes[0]
                        
            if ch not in banned:
                store=store+ch
                
    return store
```

These are the test given:

**Test 1:**

```py
print('Test 1')
print('Expected:abcd#')
print('Actual  :' + mask_out('abcde', 'e', '#'))
print()
```

**Test 2:**

```py
print('Test 2')
print('Expected:#$solute')
print('Actual  :' + mask_out('absolute', 'ab', '#$'))
print()
```

**Test 3:**

```py
print('Test 3')
print('Expected:121hon')
print('Actual  :' + mask_out('python', 'pyt', '12'))
print()
```

I've got the answer for test 1 and 2 but there were no output regarding test 3(it is probably due to error in my second if) and i have no idea why. I am really new to python and i tried changing the second to elif there is a syntax error. Please help me thank you.

Comment: What happens after this if? "if len(banned)==len(substitutes):" maybe you can find it out yourself

Comment: Please edit your question with appropriate formatting. Rn it's difficult to read.

Comment: @Karina i edited it already, its in the queue i guess...

Comment: hey @Karina , seems like u have the privilage to access to the review queues, can u accept my edit on this question?

Comment: @Karina its ok, anyway, its updated now...

Answer (score 0):

##### typos

it should be `substitutes` as you stated in the beginning of your function, not `substitute`.

##### IndexError

`store=store+substitutes[i]` will produce `IndexError` because of this part of code:

```py
for i in range(0,len(banned)): # 0, 1, 2 --> len(banned) = 3
    if i<=len(substitute): # 0, 1, 2 --> len(substitutes) = 2

        if banned[i]==ch:
            store=store+substitutes[i] # IndexError, substitutes[2] does not exist
    if i>len(substitute): #why do you need this if anyway?
        store=store+substitutes[0]
```

## Working code:

```py
def mask_out(sentence, banned, substitutes):
    store=""

    if len(banned)==len(substitutes):
        for ch in sentence:
            if ch in banned:
                for i in range(0,len(banned)):
                    if banned[i]==ch:
                        store=store+substitutes[i]
            if ch not in banned:
                store=store+ch
#     return store
    elif len(banned) > len(substitutes):
         for ch in sentence:
            if ch in banned:
                for i in range(0,len(banned)):
                    if banned[i]==ch:
                        store=store+substitutes[i%len(substitutes)]
                        
            if ch not in banned:
                store=store+ch
                
    return store
```

notice that:

1. `return store` in the middle of the function is not necessary, you are saving your variable store until the end of the function anyway, so leave it for last.
2. the second `if` should be `elif`.
3. `i%len(substitutes)` basically means 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1 and so on.
4. Loophole in the code: you did not address what happen `if len(banned) < len(substitute):`.

## Alternative code (shorter version)

```py
def maskout(sentence, banned, substitutes):

    store = ''
    if len(banned) > len(substitutes):
        for i in range(len(banned)):
            store = store + substitutes[i%len(substitutes)]
    else:
        replace_output = substitutes
    newsentence = sentence.replace(banned, store)
    return newsentence
```